# No route matches [GET] "/" when trying to add the gem devise

Tags: ruby, routes, devise

The error comes with

> Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.

`routes.rb` already has

```
devise_for :users
```

I am not sure how to fix this error. I have tried `rake routes` in the GIT terminal with the result:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'routes' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
```

Running in development mode on local server.

Answer (score 0):

So few things:

Firstly, `rake routes` has been removed - I have no idea why tbh, but it is `rails routes` now instead.

Secondly, `devise` is adding its routes, but you still need to have some ohter content that devise is to guard access to. You can create a simple `HomeController`:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render html: "home"
  end
end
```

and use this as your root route:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for ...
root to: "home#show"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Actually fixed by restarting my computer!